# Launch third-party app, through intent, while screen is off and phone is locked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wake-lock

My app needs to launch a third-party app (Google Now) while the screen is off and the phone is locked. Right now I'm using a combination of KeyGuardManager and Wakelocks to do this, but it seems to be very unreliable only working for 50% of phones about 50% of the time. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a problem with my current code? Thanks in advance

```
public void activateGoogleNow() {
    stopListening();
    if (myAudioManager != null) {
        myAudioManager.startListening();
    }
    if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getBoolean(
        "listen_screen_off", false)) {
        final KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        final PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (!powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
            WakelockManager.turnOnScreen(context);
            final Handler waitForUnlock = new Handler(
                    new Handler.Callback() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                            startGoogleNow();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (!powerManager.isScreenOn()) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                    }
                    myAudioManager.lockscreenDeactivated = true;
                    KeyguardLock mLock = keyguardManager
                            .newKeyguardLock("OpenMic");
                    mLock.disableKeyguard();
                    waitForUnlock.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            }).start();
        } else {
            startGoogleNow();
        }
    } else {
        startGoogleNow();
    }
}

private void startGoogleNow() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
            "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
        | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void turnOnScreen(Context context) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
        PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "Open Mic screen");
    wl.acquire(1000);
}
```

Comment: Where are you using this code ? If the phone is asleep maybe you need AlarmManager to wake it up

Comment: In a service, that has a wakelock

Comment: do you check if the service really acquires the wake lock ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Well I do while(!powerManager.isScreenOn()) {sleep} Is that enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the only thing I am doing different is add PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK flag also (which seems to work well at least for 2.3 and 4.0 phones):

```
pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP)
```

Comment: It seems like the screen wakes up fine, it's more a problem with the lockscreen being disabled, I'm guessing that if I disable keyguard before the screen is on, it doesn't work?

Comment: correct, the way I do it is wake up the handset, then disable the keyguard.

Comment: Ok I tried changing this code, still unreliable... any other ideas?